# Meaning of a constructor

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

All along I thought that one of purposes of constructors is to create new internal objects in the class and set their values. But when I tried in Silverlight create control (it were controls for mobile payment) in MainPage constructor I got an NullReferenceException inside third party assembly. When I moved creation code to the button handler it worked fine.

Question: Is this specific Silverlight behaviour or I understand constructor's mission not right?

```
    // Constructor
    public MainPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        //Exception
        Banner Banner = new GeneralBanner (ContentPanel);
    }

    // Banner
    public GeneralBanner (Grid contentPanel)
    {
        AdBanner = new InneractiveAd (AppId, InneractiveAd.IaAdType.IaAdType_Interstitial,
            ContentPanel, 30, Options);
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception?  What code throws the exception?  We can't just guess.

Comment: It really depends of what you're doing exactly inside the constructor. When working with Controls, your code might access components which are not yet initialized fully. Usually there are special events which are triggered when controls are initialized. This is not specific to Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor does do basic initialization as per your thoughts and that is standard. But don't associate this failure due to a design of an external control with that synopsis of constructor. It appears that this control relies on other items which have not been sized at this time and are probably failing due to height and width returning *nan* values due to not being measured during the time of your initial construction in the main page.

See the [Silverlight Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to understand more why the banner is failing during initial construction.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it because I am newbie in Silverlight and in UI too. In case when I need to do something immediately after Page construction I must use special events as noticed above (like FrameworkElement.Loaded Event)?

Comment: @Ghosthack You will have to experiment, but it happens to all of us. Loaded event sounds like a good one. Since MainPage is the first page of the whole system verses an page navigated to, it may not play the same as others do; but again keep experimenting.